# Get child item count to only show on folders, not on documents too

Tags: 2013, column, view, folder, counter

Part 1: For the main all documents view, I have only folders which show the item child count. That is how I want it, but then, when I click into the folder which only has documents in it, I would like to not see the item child count column because it is only documents, so obviously the item child count is zero.

Part 2: I would also like to be able to change the columns being shown once I click into the folder. For example, when just looking at all folders, I would like to be able to show just the item child count column, but then when I click into the folder which shows only documents, I would like to see all of my normal columns that I have all of my information in in my other views.

Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, this is how SharePoint works.

Are you comfortable with JavaScript?
If so you can use Client Side Rendering (CSR) to rewrite the Views anyway you want

- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views
- https://github.com/andrei-markeev/cisar